# Customize input type='range'

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to use html5 **input type=range** such that it should only work on slider when the user slides the cursor not when the user directly clicks on any point on the bar.

```html
<input type="range" id="myRange" value="90">
```

Comment: @Swellar this is a social platform and the only purpose is sharing problems and getting the solution if someone has already solved the problem in past .Just to make the question easy to understand and sort it's not necessary to put everything here. If you can't solve the problem keep discouraging people by downvote and promote your very one made the theory of no attempt .Everyone coming here already knows that they are here to help other so I can't understand your logic.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach might get you going:

1. Cache the current value and the mouse position on mouse-down event
2. On mouse-up event, if the mouse position is still same (i.e. a click), reset the value.

Something like:

```
$(function () {
  var lastValue = null;
  var lastMousePos = null;
    $('#myRange').on('mousedown', function(e) {
      lastValue = e.target.value
      lastMousePos = [e.pageX, e.pageY]
    })
  $('#myRange').on('mouseup', function(e) {
      mousePos = [e.pageX, e.pageY]
      if(mousePos[0] == lastMousePos[0] && mousePos[1] == lastMousePos[1]) {
        $(e.target).val(lastValue)
      }
    })
})
```

Here is a link to a working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqJmaw

I won't recommend changing the default behavior, and the solution might suffer from a visual glitch. If that's ok with you, you may try the solution.

-- Edited after OP comment --

If you are not ok with the visual glitch and are ready to do more hacky stuff (probably not a good idea), you can use a secondary input to hide the glitch. Here is another sample implementation, still with a very minor glitch, if you can notice!: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLQjdp

Comment: This is working fine but its running back which is not looking fine can we do anything around this?